# on the same mysql host how do I transfer wordpress posts from on database to another?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

on the same mysql host how do I transfer wordpress posts from on database to another?

what scripts or tools would you recommend?

Comment: You do know you can have more than one connection?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I do know i could have more than one connection. but im a noob at creating these application and was thinking if there are any made scripts out there that could help me hasten the process

Comment: is this transfer a one-time event ? Why don't you use the *Export* tool, or a dump of the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migrating wordpress databases (content) from one database to another (regardless if they are on the same host or across the world), you should really take a look at wp-migrate-db-pro.

I've been using this for my professional WP work for over a year, and it has saved me TONS of time. It is really easy to use too.

Note: I don't get paid by them to promote it...though it would be nice to!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ <- free version I think

https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/ <- what I use and highly recommend.